# Непонятный Traceback, где ошибка?

Tags: python, обработка-ошибок

код

```
import json
import requests

class Session:
    def __init__(self, login, password):
        self.login = login
        self.password = password
        self.responce = None
        self.url = 'https:****'

    def logger(self):
        requests.get(self.url)
        login_data = dict(self.login, self.password)
        requests.post(url=self.url, data=login_data)
        page = requests.get(url='https:****')
        print(page.content)


new = Session(login='****', password='****')
new.logger()
```

что это значит и как его исправить?

```
<pre><code>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='69.168.237.233', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /users/sign_in (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)'),))

</pre></code>
```

Answer (score 2):

Извините что не могу в комментарии ответить ибо порог баллов не дает. Явно же видно что ошибка в сертификации посредством `SSL протокола`. Было использовано максимум попыток для установления `защищённого соединения`. Ваш код мы не видим, мы же не телепаты чтоб угадывать что там написанно. Обновите вопрос с кодом и может вы получите ответ на свой вопрос.

**UPD:**

Ошибка может быть вызвана на `стороне сервера` что может быть правдоподобно. Но также большинство `SSL ошибок` возникает за частую из-за того мы не придерживаемся сессии к подключению. Загляните сюда - *http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/* там написано все про сессии и сертификаты.

**Строиться сессия таким образом:**

```
s = requests.Session() #объект сессии

s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789') #запрос посредством придерживания сессии 
r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies') 

print(r.text) 
#Вывод: '{"cookies": {"sessioncookie": "123456789"}}'
```

Дальше я думаю вы сами переделаете свой код. Удачи!

Comment: код уже добавила

Comment: @NadiiaKindrachuk обновил